# Greatest common divisor of two specified sequences of numbers (search for equality)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I consider two sequences of numbers $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $B=\{k-a_1,...,k-a_n\}$, where $a_1 \le a_2 \le ... \le a_n \le k$.

**I am looking for such conditions under which**: $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = \gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n)=1$.

**In more general form**: $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = \gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n) \ge 1$.

---

It can be seen that the problem is solved only in a particular forms.

I found only four particular solutions.

1. If there is such a number $\exists a_s \in A: k-a_t=a_s$, where $a_t \in A$ then $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = \gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n)$.
2. Let $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)=e$ and $\gcd(a_n-a_1,...,a_2-a_1)=E$. If $e=E$ and $e\mid k$, then $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = \gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n)$.
3. Let $P=p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_n$ denotes the primorial equaling the product of the first $n$ prime numbers and $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime number. Let $a_i=\frac{P}{p_i}$ and $k=P$, then $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = \gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n) = 1$.
4. Let $\gcd(k-a_1,...,k-a_n) = 1$ and $a_i\mid k, \forall a_i \in A$, then $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n) = 1$.

**I am convinced that there are other solutions, but I can not find them yet.
I will be grateful for any help.**

Comment: What if I took $k=a_n+1$?

Comment: I agree, also a decision on the similarity of 4. But very trivial.

Comment: Why have you written $\equiv$ here?  Normally I'd think that denoted congruence modulo some number but there's no $\pmod{m}$ here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try. Call $k$ to be good, if $d_k\triangleq (k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)>(a_1,\dots,a_n)=1$. If $k$ is good, it then follows that, there is a prime $p$, such that $p\mid k-a_i$ for every $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$. In particular, $a_1\equiv \cdots\equiv a_n\equiv k\pmod{p}$. Hence, if $k$ is good, then there necessarily is a prime $p$ at which $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are all congruent.

Now, if $k$ is such that, if for all prime $p$, there is an $i$ with $k-a_i\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, we then have that $(k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)=1$. In particular, a sufficient condition is as follows. If the collection $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is such that, for every prime $p$, there exists $i <j$ such that $a_i\not\equiv a_j\pmod{p}$, we have that for any $k$, $(k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the point. But what does the expression "k is good" mean?

Comment: Just a vocabulary that, if $d_k=(k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)>1$. Nothing super fancy/necessary either.

Comment: Let $P=\{p_1,...,p_s\}, p_s \le a_1$. If for each $p \in P$ in the set ${a_1, ..., a_n}$ exists at least one pair $a_i, a_j: a_i \not\equiv a_j \pmod{p}$ on specific $p$ then $\gcd\{a_1, ..., a_n\}=1$. Only one thing I don't understand - is how to prove that if $a_i \not\equiv a_j \pmod{p}$ then also for the same $p: k-a_i \not\equiv k-a_j \pmod{p}, \forall k \in N$.

Comment: Because, if $p\mid k-a_i$ for every $i $, if holds that,  $a_1\equiv a_2\equiv \cdots \equiv k\pmod{p}$, right? Hence, as long as you ensure $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ has two distinct elements modulo $p$ for every $p$ prime, you have that for every $k$, $(k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)=1$, no?

Comment: This not valid for $n=a_1=2$. For example, $\gcd\{2,9\}=1$ but if $k=16$, then $\gcd\{7,14\}=2$.

Comment: Виталий: The condition I have stated is quite different. I say, for every $k$, $(k-a_1,\dots,k-a_n)=1$, provided for every prime $p$, the sequence $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ has at least two members distinct in modulo $p$. In your example, this is not valid: For $p=7$. In fact, for the case of two numbers, it clearly doesn't hold, as we can take any prime $p\mid a_2-a_1$, right?

Comment: Is I correct if I say that we consider the prime numbers only until $a_1$, i.e. provided $a_1 \le ... \le a_n$ we consider only $p \le a_1$? Or this is my mistake and it is necessary to consider $p \le a_n$?

Comment: Let's take $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$, not to deal with annoying equalities. In this case,  I think we need to consider $p\leqslant a_n$. For $p>a_n$, the. sequence is clearly distinct. However, $p\leqslant a_1$ is not enough, as demonstrated by the following example: Take $a_1=k$, $a_j=(j-1)p+k$ for each $j\geqslant 2$.